# custom base page for razor helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, view-helpers

I have a project where I have several custom properties and static methods available to the base WebPage class of a Razor view...  ie,  I have...

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="myNamespace.WebView">
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

in my web.config.  this is great.  However, in my helper files, it is using the existing base class...

In this case, if I want to get access to some of those methods/properties/etc...  I have to call the `CurrentPage` object, cast it to my custom baseclass object, then get the methods I want.  In order to make the markup in the helpers simpler and cleaner, I would like to just define some static properties to grab the relevant data...

I have accomplished this nicely with some static methods and properties inside of a `@functions{}` block, but I would like to override the base class that exposes the `CurrentPage` property instead, so that I have it available by default in all of my helper files, and I won't have to repeat code...

It looks like the HelperPage implements the `WebPageRenderingBase`...

looking at the MSDN doc for the [RazorPagesSection configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.razor.configuration.razorpagessection.pagebasetype%28v=vs.99%29.aspx), it doesn't look like there is anywhere else to modify it...

is there a similar configSection that I can define to override the HelperPage base type???  this would be super helpful.  thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about `@Html` helpers?

Comment: @BuildStarted no...  when using the @helpers section, the helper methods get statically compiled.  They do, however, have available certain properties (such as `CurrentPage`).  what I would like to do is override the base class which they are getting those properties from.  this is similar to how you can override the base view page as described [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/21/changing-base-type-of-a-razor-view.aspx)